# What exactly is kinetics

Tags: sdk, kinect

The Kinect for Windows SDK beta is a programming toolkit for application developers. It enables the academic and enthusiast communities easy access to the capabilities offered by the Microsoft Kinect device connected to computers running the Windows 7 operating system.

But what kind of application we can build by using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [example](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/kinect/) projects using it.

Following some other useful links:

- The [OpenKinect](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Main_Page) project
- Primesense [OpenNI](http://openni.org/)(Primesense makes the sensor inside Kinect)
- Softkinetic [iisu](http://www.softkinetic.com/Developers/Freeiisulicence.aspx)

Comment: @learner123 not necessarily; you can build other applications using the SDK.